# Advise how to write a simple test for this javascript snippet?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I'm trying to start unit testing (not using any testing frameworks) for my javascripts.

Here's one example of it.

```
var obj = {};

obj.disableBtn = function ($btn, style) {
  $btn.attr('disabled','disabled').addClass('disabled').removeClass(style);
};
```

The use case is as such:

```
obj.disableBtn($('.submit'), 'btn-blue');
```

What it does is simply add the `disabled` attribute, add the `disabled` class, and remove the `btn-blue` style.

Please advise how would a typical test case look like in this case.

I have a little knowledge on testing using `assert()`, but have no idea how to go about it when it involves verifying the result on HTML elements.

Comment: is this part of a website? couldn't you just create a mini site with the objects/elements and scripts that you need, and open it up in a browser and then open up the developer tools and click the button, then create a button that would undo it, and click away?

Comment: Hey @resting! You marked my answer as correct. Does that mean that you figured it out yourself? `assert( willBeAnAmazingProgrammer(SE.users.resting) ) => true`

Comment: @MartinJosefsson I figured that I could write an assert that `disabled` attribute was added and `btn-blue` class was removed. Its the same principle with what you and @Dan1701 wrote, with the only difference of using a unit testing framework. Both are correct, but I have to chose 1. I choose your's for simplicity's sake. But thanks to both :)

Comment: @resting that's awesome! I guess most the testing framework as well as normal `assert()`s really are glorified `==` or `===`. So in the end pretty simple when you *get* it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate that you do assert()'s. They're simple and powerful, and non-magical.

You can test anything that is readable by code. Think "if I can `if` this, then I can `assert` it".

If you want to write a test for something that updates markup, then the question is 'how can I with code get the information I want to test?'.

If you're using jQuery (it seems so) then have you test get the button with the selector `$('.myButton')`. How would you write and `if` to check the property of this button? I think you can do that. Then use the same code in your `assert`. You're closer than you think, you can do it!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a JS unit testing framework, such as [qUnit](http://qunitjs.com/). There's no need to reinvent unit testing tools from scratch, and you will be able to focus on testing your specific functionality.

You could then create a unit test that creates a button which is not disabled and has the "active" style properties attached to it. Next, run your `disableBtn` function and assert that the button is disabled and no longer has the style attached to it. The unit test code would then look something like:

```
ok(true === yourButton.prop("disabled"));
ok(false === yourButton.hasClass('btn-blue'));
```

(jQuery functions used here since we're mostly concerned about the unit testing code. You can of course check the attributes using vanilla JS).

Comment: Of course, it can be helpful to mess around writing your own unit testing api as a learning exercise. Just remember the programmer's virtues ( http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LazinessImpatienceHubris ) if you start to think about using them for a project, and use a library instead.